# sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ } : No longer allowed. Fix?

Tags: perl, local, uniq

Please read first the UPDATE below !!!!

As can be seen elsewhere on stackoverflow, the following perl sub has been popular for some years for extracting the unique elements of a list

`sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }`

However, since some recent perl version, the above code produces the error

```
syntax error at line 2, near "sub uniq "
Can't use global $_ in "my" at test5.pl line 2, near "{$_"
syntax error at test5.pl line 2, near "++,"
```

and @_ is similarly disallowed. There is various advice to be found that one should use "local $_" and some such, but I cannot get it to work. Also it seems that maybe sub uniq needs to become a function that returns the  unique list?

In short: What does the canonical one-liner/function/sub uniq definition look like now? (perl 5.34)

UPDATE: user hobbs had the right idea. It was a typo/syntax error, namely a missing semicolon. A simple example (contrived but makes the point) to generate the error message is to feed the following two lines into perl

```
1
sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }
```

And to make the error message go away, just add the semicolon

```
1;
sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }
```

The error message seemed very "realistic" to me, so I overlooked the possibility of a simple syntax error. Hopefully I can be forgiven :).
If nothing else this post can serve as en example that a seemingly very relevant error message should not always be taken literally.

Comment: `perl -Mstrict -wE'sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }; say for uniq(2,6,2)'` works (prints lines `2`, `6`), on v5.37.2.  (I tested with an array variable as well. In `tcsh` need to escape the `!`.) Try to produce a complete (minimal) program for a demo and you'll probably find the error that way.

Comment: It says [in perldiag for that error message](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag#Can't-use-global-%25s-in-%25s) that "_You tried to declare a magical variable as a lexical variable.  ..._".  Perhaps that can help you identify the error

Comment: My guess is that you have miscalculated the line number when finding that error. If you don't have a text editor that can help you find the line, you can print it with `perl -ne'print if $. == 102' test.pl`

Comment: Wow -- an interesting error!  Thanks for updating.  I would _not_ expect that error for that input! (The  parser got really confused there :)

Comment: Interesting indeed. The error message seemed so "spot on" that I could hardly imagine that it was  due to a missing semicolon. Thanks to everyone for helping out. If anyone thinks it was useful to see this anomaly, maybe give it an upvote so I don't look so bad ;).

Comment: Hm, wait -- that code (`1 sub uniq ...`) is a plain syntax error (I didn't look carefully at first) ...?  That's not the `my $_`-kind of an error.  It's somewhere else...

Comment: If I run a oneliner with that uniq code with a 1 before I get a lot more errors than that one, including the fairly odd `"my" variable %seen masks earlier declaration in same statement`, and two syntax error. I think it may be impossible to get your $_ error without a syntax error to go along with it, since it relies on broken code. If you had included all the relevant errors, it would have been easier to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just made a typo somewhere. There's nothing wrong with that function, and I've tested it to work both on 5.34.0 and blead using the code copied out of your question. I would probably use [List::Util::uniq](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#uniq) (or uniqnum or uniqstr in special cases) or [List::UtilsBy::uniq_by](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy#uniq_by), but nothing has changed in Perl to break that snippet.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I wouldn't call that snippet the canonical way to remove duplicates; I'd say that's List::Util's `uniq`.

That said, there's no problem with the code you posted. Specifically, it doesn't produce the error you claim it does. The code is perfectly valid in all version of Perl since at least 5.6, including 5.34 and 5.36.

```
$ 5.34t/bin/perl -wE'
   sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }
   say for uniq qw( a b a b c );
'
a
b
c
```

---

The quoted error message results from passing a punctuation variable (e.g. `$!`, `$1`, etc) to `my`.

```
$ perl -e'my $!;'
Can't use global $! in "my" at -e line 1, near "my $!"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

A program that once worked wouldn't normally start giving this error as a result of an upgrade, since Perl has been giving this error since lexical variables and `my` have been introduced in Perl 5.6.<sup>[1]</sup>

There's one exception: `my $_`.

5.10 introduced the three related features smart-matching, `given` and lexical `$_` (`my $_`).

They have many problems. So many that the concept of experimental features was introduced in 5.18, and these were downgraded to experimental features.

The experiments were deemed failures. While smart-matching and `given` have been hard to remove (since so many people are using the experimental features), that's not the case for lexical `$_`. 5.24 saw its removal. Attempts to use `my $_` in 5.24+ results in the error you posted once again.

```
$ 5.8/bin/perl -e'my $_;'
Can't use global $_ in "my" at -e line 1, near "my $_"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

$ 5.10t/bin/perl -e'my $_;'

$ 5.16t/bin/perl -e'my $_;'

$ 5.18t/bin/perl -e'my $_;'
Use of my $_ is experimental at -e line 1.

$ 5.22t/bin/perl -e'my $_;'
Use of my $_ is experimental at -e line 1.

$ 5.24t/bin/perl -e'my $_;'
Can't use global $_ in "my" at -e line 1, near "my $_"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The code you posted doesn't pass a punctuation variable to `my`. As such, it doesn't produce the error you claim it does.

If it did use `my` with a punctuation variable, the error would be resolved by replacing the `my $X` with `local $X`, `local *X` or `for $X ()`.

---

1. I'm guessing it's been giving the error since 5.6. I can only verify back to 5.8.

Comment: Thanks, interesting background of  recent changes in perl. Please see UPDATE above for what was the underlying cause in my case.

Comment: The code you added produces `syntax error at -e line 2, near "sub uniq " [...]`. Don't ignore the first error in the future.

Comment: Updated with both lines of the error message

Comment: No, you're still missing the *first* error. You're doing exactly the opposite of what I said. You should be paying attention to the first error, not the others. That's the most relevant one. Subsequent errors can never be trusted, because they can be caused by the first one.

Comment: You are correct. fixed.